# Render a specific className when active with classNames and Tailwind

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, classname

I'm using **Tailwinds CSS** and **classNames** package.

I'm rendering out 2 `div`s and I want to check if one of them has am `active` class, then set a specific background color className `bg-[#000]` to it.

- I tried using `'bg-[#000]': 'active'` check but this just inserts the background color on all elements.

How can we set a specific style to an active element with `Tailwind` and `classNames`?

Thank you!

**Screenshots:**

Here's a screenshot of the tags, the 1st one is currently active.
But the second one which is not active also has the `bg-[#000]` class.

[image]

**Code:**

```js
list.map((page, index) => {
  return ( 
  <div 
    key = {index}
    onClick = {() => setCurrentListIdx(index)}
    className = {
      classNames('bullets__item m-1.5 h-2 w-2 cursor-pointer rounded-full bg-[#e0e0e0]', 
      {
        active: currentListIdx === +index,
        'bg-[#000]': 'active',
       }
      )}
    ></div>
  )
})
```

Comment: How does the class look in your css?

Comment: Hi @biberman, thank you for asking. I just updated my question with a screenshot to show the classes. Please let me know if it answers your question, thank you!

Comment: No, there is no CSS code. But Zane Taylor answered your question correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the conditional `'bg-[#000]': 'active'`, you're passing the string `'active'` rather than a variable or an expression to evaluate. This is returning `true` because JS strings are truthy, and so always adding the class. The [`classNames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) utility doesn't appear to allow checking against currently applied class names in its conditionals object this way.

You could alternatively use the same conditional for both class names: `currentListIdx === +index`, so both classes would be added when this condition is met.

Comment: Thank you, Zane :) 
I realized I was trying to use Tailwind but in CSS logic, the `active` class has no use at this point. I changed `active: currentListIdx === +index` to `'bg-[#000]': currentListIdx === +index` and it works fine as expected.